# Python OpenPyxl column data filter

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to apply a data filter to column B in my XLSX file,
This is my code :

```
import os
import glob
import csv
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def convert_csv():
    for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
        newfile = csvfile[:-4]
        workbook = Workbook(newfile + '.xlsx')
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        with open(csvfile, 'rb') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for r, row in enumerate(reader):
                for c, col in enumerate(row):
                    worksheet.write(r, c, col)
        workbook.close()

wb = load_workbook('report.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
#ws.auto_filter.ref = 'B:B'
ws.auto_filter.add_filter_column(1, '501', blank=False)
print ws.auto_filter.filter_columns
wb.save('outgoing.xlsx')
```

What I'm trying to achieve is convert a CSV file to XLSX (which is OK)
and then apply data filter to the column with specific vals (in my case I want to filters only rows that got '501' or '502).

I'm able to add the data filter to the column if I uncomment

```
#ws.auto_filter.ref = 'B:B'
```

But then the file is not readable any more.
I've tried to read the documentation for the OpenPyxl but that didn't helped much.

Thanks

-- SOLVED ! --
Was almost there,
the correct code is :

```
ws.auto_filter.ref = 'B:B'
ws.auto_filter.add_filter_column(0, ['501','502'], blank=False)
```

The column number (0) is an outcome of the reference that I set before,
since I set only 1 column to be filtered (B:B) then I'm working on column 0
if I would have set A:B as my range and still wanted to filter B, I would have used column 1 as I was thinking.

Comment: write your solution as a answer, and then check it as "aceppted answer"